# I want to add WHERE clause in this query

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

```
$saleOrderTableAlias = 's_o';

//Order payment model
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment');

//Order payment collection
$collection = $orderPayment->getResourceCollection();

//Table join
$collection->join(
    array($saleOrderTableAlias => 'sales/order'),
    'parent_id=s_o.entity_id'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clauses are added with

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(attribute, conditions)
```

or

```
$collection->getSelect()->where(conditions)
```